# What is this Python function called?

Tags: python

I saw this code.

```
def char2num(s):
    return {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[s]
```

Then if you call this function:

```
map(char2num, '123456789')
```

You will get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

My question is why this (not the `map()` function, but the `char2num` function) works and what is is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char2num` uses a dictionary:

```
{'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4,
 '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}
```

Calling the function looks up the character and returns a corresponding integer:

```
return {...}[s]
```

It is simply a dictionary lookup:

```
>>> d = {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4,
...      '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}
>>> d['0']
0
>>> d['8']
8
```

The function could be expressed as:

```
char2num = {str(i): i for i in range(10)}.__getitem__
```

too, using the [`dict.__getitem__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) (normally invoked by `somedict[...]`) and expressing the dictionary procedurally in a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> char2num = {str(i): i for i in range(10)}.__getitem__
>>> char2num('0')
0
>>> char2num('8')
8
```

Comment: Thanks! Is your method also a function, or a list comprehension?

Comment: @shidangai: it is a dictionary comprehension that produces the exact same dictionary, then looks up the bound `__getitem__` method on that dictionary.